# algorithm for finding highest score using array and output the index of that (highest score)

Tags: c++, arrays

so i have this program which supposed to asks 5 users of students in a 50 items quiz using array. it must output the average score and highest score of the quiz, also it must show the index at which that element(highest score) was found. so far i have sorted out how to find the average and i also have the solve codes for the highest but it gives me the wrong output.. here is my progress so far.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  clrscr();
  const int input = 5;
  int student[input];
  int sum=0;
  int ave=0;

  cout<<"Please enter the score of "<<input<<" student\n";

  for(int i=0; i<input; i++)
  {

    cout<<"student "<<i+1<<":";
    cin>>student[i];
    sum+=student[i];

    ave= sum/input;

  }
    int highest=1;
    int a=student[0];
    for(i=1; i<a; i++)
      {
       if(student[i]<highest)
       highest=student[i];

      }

    cout<<"Average score of the student is "<<ave<<"."<<endl;
    cout<<"Highest score is "<<highest<<"."<<endl;

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell me where is my mistakes here? i've been solving this program since last night... :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `if (student[i] < highest)` should be `if (student[i] > highest)`, and initialization should be `highest = student[0]`. and remove `a` and replace it by `input` in your second loop.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` -- I feel sorry for you if you're supposed to be using such an old compiler.  Is this Turbo C++ from 25 years ago?

Comment: yeah right! :) and i've just changed that now but still i got the wrong output bro! :)

Comment: @YuSop As mentioned, use the debugger to step through your code and check the variable values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah i was using that because my school uses that for our lab coding... :(

Comment: @YuSop -- I don't know why these institutions use these old compilers that do not reflect the state of C++ as it stands today (or even as of 1998).  You walk into a job interview writing things like `#include <iostream.h>`, you'll be embarrassed.

Comment: @Jarod42 is this what you mean?

int highest=student[0];
 for(i=1; i<student[1]; i++)
      {
       if(student[i]>highest)
    highest=student[i];

      }

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah right.. but i'm hoping to learn more here than on the school. haha

Comment: @YuSop: I mean [that](http://ideone.com/XOrDm0).

Comment: @Jarod42 okay i just did changed it. but apparently it still gave me the wrong highest number. what it gives as the highest one is the first array score in the element. any idea why?

Comment: @YuSop -- And once you get a modern C++ compiler, the answer is `int *ptrhighest = std::max_element(student, student + input); double ave = std::accumulate(student, student + input, 0.0) / input; int index = std::distance(student, ptrhighest); highest = *ptrhighest;`

Answer (score 1):

you are searching for the highest or the lowest?

```
if(student[i] < highest)
     highest = student[i]; // ?
```

also what is this:

```
int a = student[0]; // example the user enters 100 then 
    for(i = 1; i < a; i++) // i < 100 reading outbands of the array
```

declare a variable to store the index of highest value and correct it to:

```
int index = 0;

for(i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
     if(student[i] > highest) // > not <
     {
         highest = student[i];
         index = i;
     }
}

cout << "Average score of the student is " << ave << "."<<endl;
cout << "Highest score is " <<highest << "." << endl;
cout << "index of highest score: " << index << endl;
```

Comment: This solves only part of the problem, as the OP needs to output the **index** of the highest.